# Display Data from multiple tables

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm new with JSF / Java and relational DB queries.

I'm trying to Display data from two tables in one datatable.

I have two tables tblUser and tblCity.

For These tables I've got two models Users and City.
Also got a UserDAO and a UserController.

I'd like to know how to select user data from tblUser and select City data from tblCity and Display them on my view. With MVC style.

Model:

```
public class User{
   private Integer user_id;
   private String user_name;
   private Integer City_id;

   //getter and setter
   ...
}


public class City{
   private Integer city_id;
   private String city_name;

   //getter and setter
   ...
}
```

My Controller

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public List<User> showUser(){

   List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
   users= userDAO.showUserList();
   return users;

}
```

My DAO

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class userDAO{

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of patientDAO
     */
    private final connectToDB con = new connectToDB();

    public userDAO() {
    }
    public List<User> showUserList() {

            Connection dbConnection = null;

            dbConnection = con.getDBConnection();

            PreparedStatement pstmt = dbConnection
                    .prepareStatement("select a.user_id, a.user_name, b.city_name"
                            + " from users a, cities b WHERE a.city_id = b.city_id");
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
            List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();

            while (rs.next()) {

                User user = new User();
                City city = new City();

                user.setUser_Id(rs.getInt("user_id"));
                user.setUser_Id(rs.getString("user_name"));

                city.setCity_Name(rs.getInt("city_name"));      


                users.add(user);
                cities.add(city);
            }
            // close resources
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();

            dbConnection.close();


            return users;
        }
}
```

My View

```
<p:dataTable id="userDT" var="user" value="#{userController.showUserList()}">
    <p:column width="200" headerText="User Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.user_name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column width="200" headerText="City Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{...}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that one `User` has one `City`, you can add a `city` attribute to the `User` class:

```
public class User{
    ...
    private City city;

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    ...
}
```

In your `userDAO`, at the end of the while loop of the `showUserList()` method, put the city in the user object:

```
...
while (rs.next()) {
    User user = new User();
    City city = new City();

    user.setUser_Id(rs.getInt("user_id"));
    user.setUser_Id(rs.getString("user_name"));

    city.setCity_Name(rs.getInt("city_name"));      

    user.setCity(city);

    users.add(user);
}
...
```

The list of cities in the `showUserList()` method is not used outside the method, you can delete it.

And finally, edit the view like this:

```
...
<p:column width="200" headerText="City Name">
    <h:outputText value="#{user.city.city_name}" />
</p:column>
...
```